# How to track the first launch visibility of an Item on app window

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am using Qt 5.9.3. I have a QML [Item](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html) like so:

```
Item {
    id: root
    width : 400
    height: 700
}
```

How do I track when the Item was first time visible on screen of my application window? `onVisibilityChanged`?

How do I do track the same for a `MyQuickItem` which is something like this:

```
// C++ definition
class MyQuickItem : public QQuickitem {
}

// QML side
MyQuickItem {
  id: some_id
}
```

Comment: In both cases you must use onVisibilityChanged.

Comment: @eyllanesc: Does this work, when the item is created visible? And to the OP: Will the first Item ever be "visible", since there is no visible content... What do you define as "first visibility"? Once it has been completely drawn, or once the first pixel has been drawn?

Comment: @derM According to the docs: *This property holds whether the item is visible. By default this is true.*, where it is understood that when it refers to the item, it talks about when all the pixels are drawn. It would be a matter of checking if it is visible by default, I would use Component.OnCompleted to verify visibility at startup.

Comment: @eyllanesc: But it is also a property to *control whether the item is visible*.  Let's take a Item that takes a long time to draw, that is currently invisible (`visible = false`) - now we set `visible = true` - it will be true immediately, and only then start to draw. I think the **is** in the documentation might be missleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the complete code suppose like:

```
ApplicationWindow{
    visible: true
    onVisibilityChanged: {
        console.log("ApplicationWindow is ", visibility)
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("ApplicationWindow is onCompleted")
    }
    Item {
        id: root
        width : 400
        height: 700
        onVisibleChanged: {
            console.log("Item is ", visible)
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log("Item is onCompleted")
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously the `onVisibilityChanged` of `ApplicationWindow` will trigger when the `visibility` property is changed, so it triggers when you minimize and reshow the window. As you mention *the first time visible*, so I think you are looking for `Component.onCompleted`.